# How to use/call variables from another function in bash

Tags: bash

I am learning to play around with functions in bash. I have the first function read_file() that reads /etc/file and replaces ':'with a space between words (e.g root:x:0:0:root ... becomes root x 0 0 root ... ). I then want to be able to manipulate output from individual words in each of the lines. 
My second function- display__user_shell() prints our the shell for each corresponding users as is in the /etc/file.

My problem is figuring out how to call the first function  read_file() and using its variables in the display__user_shell function.

I have been able to do the above  when using input from a single line rather than reading from a file.
 i just called new_data -i.e $new_data from the  display__user_shell() function

```
read_file() {
read -p "Enter file" file
while read line
    do
        newlin=$(echo $line | tr ":" " ")
        echo newlin
    done
}
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=" "
ct=0
display__user_shell() {
readfile
    for item in $newlin;
    do
        [ $ct -eq 0 ] && name="$item";
        [ $ct -eq 6 ] && name="$item";
    done
echo "$user's shell is $shell"
}
IFS=$oldIFS
display__user_shell
```

the first line of the output should be..

root's shell is /bin/bash

Comment: is the first line: ```#!/bin/bash```?

Comment: A little omission; in the sixth line of the code, the newline (in read_line function) should  be called using $

Comment: please update the question

Comment: and yes, the "echo newlin" should be "echo ${newlin}"

Comment: Yeah it is. sorry I forgot to add it.

Comment: My problem is how to call readline() and its variable newlin from the function  display__user_shell(). The I have done it does not work. Apart from the omission, the rest of the code should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the implementation there is an interesting question here: how to reference variables from one function in another function. The short answer is that you can:

```
$ a() { aye=bee; }
$ b() { echo "$aye"; }
$ a
$ b
bee
```

But this is a very bad idea - Bash has "unfortunate" scoping rules different from safer languages like Java, Python, or Ruby, and code like this is very hard to follow. Instead there are several patterns you can use to produce more readable code:

- Print the value in the inner function and assign that to a value in the outer function:

  ```
  a() {
      echo 'bee'
  }
  b() {
      aye="$(a)"
      echo "$aye"
  }
  b # Prints "bee"
  ```
- Call and assign to a variable the first function in the outer scope and use it in the second function:

  ```
  a() {
      echo 'bee'
  }
  aye="$(a)"
  b() {
      echo "$aye"
  }
  b # Prints "bee"
  ```
- Treat the first and second functions as a pipeline, passing standard output of the first one to the standard input of the second one (`read` is a slow way to process a large file, but it'll serve as an example):

  ```
  a() {
      echo 'bee'
  }
  b() {
      while read -r line
      do
          echo "$line"
      done
  }
  a | b # Prints "bee"
  ```

Which one you choose depends on things like what else you intend to do with what `a` returns and whether `a` produces huge amounts of output.